# find the missing no. from the array

Tags: php

```
$var=array(1,5,6,7,11,2,.......,45,100);
```

In above array the total numbers are 99 (From 1 to 100 but missing no. is in between 1 to 100).

I want to find that missing no.

Comment: sort($var). Then do a foreach loop and increment a counter in parallel. If the counter does not match the element from the array the counter indicates the (one) missing number.

Comment: I want without sorting the array.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not homework generator.

Answer (score 0):

You can try array_diff

```
<?php
for ($ii = 0; $ii < 100; $ii++)
    $completeArray[] = $ii;

$arrayPart = array(1,3,5,7,9,11,13);

$missing = array_diff($completeArray, $arrayPart);
var_dump($missing);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would generate an array with all elements and then get the difference between the 2 arrays using [`array_diff()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php).

A simple example:

```
$all = range(1,100);
$missing = array_reverse($all);  // to show that order / keys don't matter
unset($missing[41]);             // remove 1 item

var_dump(array_diff($all, $missing));
```

results in:

```
array(1) {
  [58]=>
  int(59)
}
```

So in your case all you need is:

```
array_diff(range(1, 100), $var)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

- Sort the array.
- Using for loop, Check if (a[i] != a[i-1] + 1), then (a[i] - 1) is the missing number.

Comment: I want without sorting the array.